# Calculus Homework + Cost of Producing + Marginal Cost

Tags: word-problem

> Suppose the cost of producing x widgets is $C(x)= 5000+40x-0.02x^2$.
>
> A. What is the cost of producing widget number 31? Your answer should be a single number.
>
> (Recall that $C(x)$ is the cost of producing numbers $1,2,3,\dots$ up to $x$).
>
> B. What is the marginal cost when x=30?

For 1A I just plugged in $31$ to the $x$'s in the equation. My answer turned out to be $6259.224$. That isn't right because it said it should be a single number.

Since I don't believe my answer for 1A is right I'm not sure how to go about getting 1B.

Comment: C(31) is the cost of making a total of 31 widgets.  The problem asked for the cost of the 31st widget, not all 31!  But in what sense is '6259.224' NOT a "single number"?  Were you thinking it had to be a single digit?

Comment: I didn't think it could have a decimal place. I knew it could have multiple numbers and it obviously couldn't be a fraction but like I said I didn't know if it could have a decimal place. I still do not know how to solve 1A then if it's just looking for the 31st digit.

Answer (score 0):

The cost of producing widget number $31$ is the cost of producing $31$ widgets minus the cost of producing $30$ widgets which is:

$C(31) - C(30) $

$=(5000 + 40 \cdot 31 - 0.02 \cdot 31^2) - (5000 + 40 \cdot 30 - 0.02 \cdot 30^2)$

$= \$38.78$

Marginal cost is defined as $C'(x)$.

$C'(x) = 40 - 0.04x$

$C'(30) = 40 - 0.04 \cdot 30 = 40 - 1.20 = \$38.80$